# How to use hstore on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, hstore

As per https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/4/26/heroku_postgres_development_plan/ I did "heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev". But when I do

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration 
  def up 
    create_table :users do |t| 
      execute "CREATE EXTENSION hstore" 
      t.hstore :access 
    end 
  end 

  def down 
    drop_table :users 
      execute "DROP EXTENSION hstore" 
    end 
  end
end
```

and then "heroku run rake db:migrate" I get this error:

PG::Error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "EXTENSION" 
LINE 1: CREATE EXTENSION hstore ^ 
: CREATE EXTENSION hstore

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? `CREATE EXTENSION` was introduce in 9.0, maybe you are using an old version?

Comment: on my local development machine i'm running 9.1.4 and it works fine.  it's only on heroku that i'm having the issue

Comment: So what's the version on heroku?

Comment: not sure how to check the version of postgres on heroku but as per https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/4/26/heroku_postgres_development_plan/ i think it runs 9.1

Comment: heroku pg:info
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 1
PG Version:  9.1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally got it to work.  turns out i needed to "promote" the database using heroku pg:promote as per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-dev-plan

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to split out your migrations, one to add hstore, the other to use it;

```
class SetupHStore < ActiveRecord::Migration 
  def self.up
    execute "CREATE EXTENSION hstore"
  end

  def self.down
    execute "DROP EXTENSION hstore"
  end
end
```

to enable the extension, and the your Users migration will just add any fields and then use hstore on which ever column you want.